# Gradient boosting and quantile regression performance issues

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, quantile-regression

My goal is to develop a ML model that predicts the remaining flight time.

To do so I have different features:

- distance
- altitude
- speed
- vertical rate

Here is a plot showing the actual remaining time vs. distance for multiple flights:
[image: Remaining time vs distance]

I want to perform a quantile regression, therefore I have trained a quantile regression (q=0.9) using a gradient boosting regressor (max_depth=4).

Unfortunately it does not work as expected, the model performs poorly for shorter distances, as shown here:
[image: prediction error in function of distance for quantile 0.9]

Interestingly, at the median (0.5 quantile), the model performs as expected:
[image: prediction error in function of distance for quantile 0.5]
Changing the quantile alters the distance at which the predictions deteriorate. Here is an example with the 0.1 quantile:
[image: prediction error vs distance for quantile 0.1]

I have tried 2 different gradient boosting libraries (XGboost and LightGBM) and observe a similar outcome. I believe this is a fundamental issue, not just software or overfitting. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Progress:
I think I have identified the issue (or at least part of it): a smaller learning rate seems to worsen the problem. By 'worsen', I am referring to the portion of data for which the error is abnormally large.

Edit:
As suggested by @user2974951, here is the result for a linear quantile regression with the .9 quantile:

[image: Error vs distance for linear quantile regression]

Comment: Have you tried a quantile linear model?

Comment: I just updated the post with the results of the linear quantile regression.

Comment: Which quantile did you use for the linear model?

Comment: 0.9, sorry I should have said that

Comment: I'm not clear on what the inputs and outputs are.  Can you give some EDA or basic disgnostic plots of the target variable?  [nist 4-plot](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/4plot.htm) How many trees in your gbm/xgboost?  what is lambda?  Why do you think the relationship exists?  If you do a rough linear fit or RF fit do you get a plausible fit, or junk?  afaik the quantiles are bounds on the predictions given an input, and are more useful for getting a sense of uncertainty in your prediction and they can be jittery even in nice problems.

Comment: I think I have identified the issue: it appears to be related to the learning rate. Specifically, a smaller learning rate seems to worsen the problem. By 'worsen', I am referring to the portion of data for which the error is large.

Comment: There is heteroscedasticity. Try using a data transform like log-log or similar transform prior to modelling. This may even linearize the data, if chosen correctly.